# Complex properties about simple functions $f(x)=2x+1$ and $g(x)=3x+1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics

This problem came up while trying to prove something for one of my projects. I've checked the first few values with code but I've been looking for a mathematical proof.

> We define $f(x)=2x+1$ and $g(x)=3x+1,$ do there exist two distinct sets of operations $S$ and $S'$ with the **SAME number of elements** such that $S(1)=S'(1)?$ (e.g. $S=f(g(...(1)...)=g(f(...(1)...)=S'$ or $S=f(f(g(...(1)...))=f(f(f(...(1)...))=S'$ etc.)

If it helps, $S$ can not be comprised of solely $f(x)$, and that $S'$ can be comprised solely of $g(x)$ and I know an explicit formula based on the application of the equations. thanks!

Comment: I've noted that all possible values $S(1)$ for 20 elements have different remainders being divided by $3^{20}$

Comment: So by "set of operations" you mean a sequence of applications of $f$ or $g$? And by "number of elements" you mean the length of the sequence?

Comment: Hint: $g(f(x))>f(g(x))$. Compare the sizes of different compositions of the same length.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu would that help with proving for all cases though?

Comment: @Karl I've split the problem not into 2 cases: Case 1. when the number of fs and the number of gs is the same in S and S'. Case 2. when the number of fs and gs is not the same in S and S'.

Comment: For case 1, I can write S=ax+b and S'=cx+d. The issue though, is that I can't really compare a and c separately because of the b and d being added at the end. I'm also not sure how to deal with case 2

Comment: For case 1 you'll have $a=c$, and swapping $fg\mapsto gf$ in the sequence increases the added constant. I suggest working out some examples to see how the composition order affects the size of the result.

Comment: I agree that my observations don't completely solve case 2 (e.g. $fgg$ vs. $gff$).

Comment: @Karl ok, cool, thanks! I'll try to work on case 2 tonight I guess, but I'm not really sure where to start. I guess maybe just throwing random techniques at it.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find the answer to your question but as $f$ and $g$ have simple expressions, we can compute explicitely such "sets of operations" $S$. If we can $n$ the number of operations, $S$ can be represented by a sequence $(a_k)_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n}$ with $a_k = 0$ when $f$ appears in the $k$th position, $a_k = 1$ else. Let us write $S = S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}$ in this case. For example $S_{(0,0,1)} = f \circ f \circ g$, with the convention $S_{()}(x) = x$ (the identity is the neutral element for the composition).

Write for all $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, $\Sigma_k = \sum_{i = 1}^k a_i$. Observations enable us to conjecture the formula,
$$
S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(x) = 2^{n - \Sigma_n}3^{\Sigma_n}x + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} 2^{k - \Sigma_k}3^{\Sigma_k}.
$$
Indeed, notice that it is true at rank $n = 0$, and if it is true at rank $n$, we have for all $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n + 1})$, $S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_{n + 1})}(x) = S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(2^{1 - a_{n + 1}}3^{a_{n + 1}}x + 1)$ (simply verify that it is true for both $a_{n + 1} = 0$ and $a_{n + 1} = 1$). Therefore,
\begin{align*}
S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_{n + 1})}(x) & = S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(2^{1 - a_{n + 1}}3^{a_{n + 1}}x + 1)\\
& = 2^{n - \Sigma_n}3^{\Sigma_n}(2^{1 - a_{n + 1}}3^{a_{n + 1}}x + 1) + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} 2^{k - \Sigma_k}3^{\Sigma_k}\\
& = 2^{n + 1 - \Sigma_{n + 1}}3^{\Sigma_{n + 1}}x + \sum_{k = 0}^n 2^{k - \Sigma_k}3^{\Sigma_k},
\end{align*}
which proves the formula. In particular,
$$
S_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(1) = \sum_{k = 0}^n 2^{k - \Sigma_k}3^{\Sigma_k}.
$$

Comment: Right, the sum should start at $k = 0$, I went a bit fast on the case $n = 0$, I corrected it.

Comment: this seems like a step in the right direction, though it doesn't decode any information about the functions themselves I think